# Java non-final fields force visibility with another volatile field

Tags: java, memory, volatile

I have recently begun to understand how the Java Memory Model works (I don't fully yet).

I now understand that if I have non-final, non-volatile fields in my classes then it is possible for the value of those fields to not be immediately visible to other threads post construction e.g.

```
public class Example {
    Object a;
    Object b;

    public Example() {
      this.a = new Object();
      this.b = new Object();
    }
}

Example e = new Example();

// now imagine we are in another thread
e.a // could this in theory be null?
e.b // could this in theory be null?
```

What I'm not sure about is weather if I add a third volatile variable and set it at the end will the writes to `a` and `b` be guaranteed to be visible to other threads?

```
public class Example2 {
    Object a;
    Object b;
    volatile Object c;

    public Example2() {
      this.a = new Object();
      this.b = new Object();
      this.c = new Object();
    }
}

// some where else
Example2 e2 = new Example2();
// are e2.a and e2.b guaranteed to be visible to all other threads? I know (e2.c will be)
```

This is not something I particularly want to use but I want to understand what would happen in this case.

Comment: If thread B reads `c` after thread A has set `c`, then a _happens-before_ relationship has been created. That means thread B will see the new values of `a` and `b`. Race conditions can still happen, but the _happens-before_ relationship should stop threads from perpetually seeing stale values.

Comment: @slaw do you know under what conditions a thread could see stale values perpetually?

Comment: If thread A was writing `b`, and thread B was reading `b`, yet neither touch `c`, then thread B is not guaranteed to see the changes to `b`.

Comment: OK, so if I always write to `c` _after_ I write to `b` then `b` is guaranteed to be visible to other threads too?

Comment: Assuming the other threads also read `c` before reading `b`.

Comment: The answer of @Slaw is correct. The jmm is expressed in happens before and as long as there is a happens before edge between a write and a read, there is no data race and the code is correctly synchronized. So do not try to reason in terms of caching and stale values because it isnt relevant to understanding the jmm and caches on modern processors are coherent anyway so caches cant get out of sync.

Comment: But you cant rely on an fake volatile read/write to act like a fence because the compiler is allowed to optimize out such loads and stores.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor runs in a single thread and the instance is not "visible" to other threads until the constructor completes.

So, in this example, `a` and `b` will only be seen in other threads as null if they are subsequently set to null post-constructor.

The `volatile` keyword addresses possible optimizations in which a thread may continue to use an old value for a field after it changes on another thread due to local caching of the value.  By adding `volatile` to the field, such optimizations are disabled.

By the way, if there's a need to synchronize across threads, using volatile fields is not ideal.  Using atomic classes or other constructs from `java.util.concurrent` is advisable.

Comment: I don't think this is true: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5

Comment: Final means that the field can only have its value set once, and never changed.  Of course, if that value is a reference to another object, it doesn't mean that other object's fields can't change value, just that it will always refer to the same instance.

Comment: Final fields can be set in static initializer blocks, field declaration assignments, or constructor.  They MUST be set before the constructor completes.  This way, the JVM ensures an object is fully constructed before it can be used by any other object.

Comment: "An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields."

In my examples above the fields are not final (deliberately because I want to understand what happens in this case).

Comment: I tell you what - put together an example that demonstrates the problem, and I'll help with that.  Otherwise, I think this may be a case of the details being confusing in isolation.  Those materials referenced are very detailed and accurate, but without context, they may sound like they mean more than they really do.

Comment: I'm not asking about a problem I'm having, I'm asking about what is the Java/JVM specified behaviour in the scenario above - the scenario above is the scenario

Comment: @JosephCarrie Having the only writes in the constructor confuses things though, because the memory guarantees of object initialization sort of make the `volatile` unnecessary in the code you provided.

Comment: This is the key point I want to get at though, is the volatile there really required as per the spec?

Comment: @JosephCarrie In the specific code you provided? No, nothing indicates `volatile` needs to be there. But that also depends on how you then end up using the instance of `Example` (more specifically, the fields of the instance).

Comment: Ok what I mean in the example is another thread is accessing the fields of Example, I will update it

Comment: @JosephCarrie With the updated code, and assuming the fields are never written to after the constructor initializes them, then all other threads will see the objects you assigned to the fields in the constructor (i.e., they won't read `null`). The `volatile` is not needed, in that case.